# Como abrir uma imagem em C++ utilizando o SFML?

Tags: c++, sfml

Eu ainda estou no começo e precisa abrir uma imagem em C++ usando SFML, no momento estou utilizando um código que usa o endereço da imagem, mas tudo isso via código e o que eu preciso é que esse endereço de onde a imagem esta seja informado pelo usuário.

Exemplo:

```
c:\desktop\teste.png
```

o código que eu pretendo modificar e esse:

```
    sf::Image imagem;
if (!imagem.loadFromFile("imagem.png")) {
    cout<<"Erro ao abrir a imagem!"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: A sua pergunta não está muito clara. Parece que a dúvida é sobre como solicitar ao usuário para escolher um arquivo, e não sobre como abrir imagem em C++ com o SFML. É isso?

Answer (score 4):

Não conheço o SFML em profundidade, mas por ele ser uma biblioteca para acesso a recursos multimídia creio que ele não tem recursos para facilitar a solicitação do nome do arquivo para o usuário (ou ao menos deve ser bem difícil construir isso usando a classe `Window`).

Uma alternativa é você utilizar uma biblioteca grafica como o [Qt](http://qt-project.org/). Você poderia construir a sua própria interface gráfica para isso, mas é bastante comum (e facilita a utilização de usuários acostumados com o sistema operacional) utilizar a janela padrão de seleção de arquivo.

Com o Qt você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
#include <QFileDialog>
QString arquivo = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Abrir imagem", ".", "Arquivos PNG (*.png);; Todos os arquivos (*.*)"));
if(arquivo.length())
{
    sf::Image imagem;
    if (!imagem.loadFromFile(arquivo.toStdString())) {
        cout<<"Erro ao abrir a imagem!"<<endl;
    }
}
```

Esse código abrirá uma janela de seleção de arquivo como essa abaixo (exemplo reproduzido [dessa thread do SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259994/qfiledialog-alternative-that-uses-default-file-dialog-defined-by-os) - não cheguei a executar o código aqui), em que o usuário pode selecionar o arquivo existente ou mesmo digitar o caminho. Ao clicar no botão OK (na imagem está em outro idioma, mas não importa), a janela é fechada e o método `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName` retorna uma string com o caminho e nome do arquivo selecionado. Basta então utilizá-lo na chamada do método `Image::loadFromFile' da biblioteca SFML, como ilustrado acima.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por mais que seja uma solução correta, fácil e portável entre multiplas plataformas, eu não acho que valha a pena incluir a dependencia do Qt apenas por uma funcionalidade que pode ser implementada [por outros meios](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/14985/429). Isso dá uns 15MB de dlls a mais no windows.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal É verdade. Mas na prática isso irá depender de fatores não mencionados na pergunta, principalmente se o produto do OP precisa ou não ser portável e se a necessidade de interface gráfica dele vai além de apenas solicitar um nome de arquivo. De todas as formas, mesmo que não seja a melhor resposta, ainda assim parece bacana mantê-la para referência.

Comment: Obrigado, vou dar uma olhada tanto na biblioteca indicada quanto também na outra forma comentada. só que a minha necessidade é que ao menos a imagem seja carregada/indicada pelo usuário, isso pode ser em código no terminal ou como o Luiz publicou atrás de uma biblioteca. Att

Answer (score 4):

O `SFML` sozinho não oferece nenhuma forma de pedir ao usuário para selecionar uma imagem. Mas, você pode usar um Diálogo de Seleção de Imagem a partir de um *toolkit* tal como o Qt, wxWidgets ou usar a API do próprio sistema alvo do seu programa.

Para Windows (usando WIN32 API) você pode abrir uma janela para selecionar uma imagem usando a seguinte função:

```
#include <Windows.h> // Para a janela de selecionar o arquivo
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

sf::Texture LoadTexture(void)
{
    OPENFILENAME ofn;

    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));

    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
    ofn.hwndOwner = 0;
    ofn.lpstrDefExt = 0;
    ofn.lpstrFile = new TCHAR[512];
    ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
    ofn.nMaxFile = 512;
    ofn.lpstrFilter = NULL;
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 0;
    ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
    ofn.lpstrTitle = L"Selecione uma Imagem";
    ofn.Flags = 0;

    GetOpenFileName(&ofn);

    // Converte para std::string.
    std::wstring wstr = ofn.lpstrFile;
    std::string str(wstr.begin(), wstr.end());

    // Armazenará a imagem.
    sf::Texture texture;

    // Verifica se o arquivo é válido e se foi possível carregar.
    if (!texture.loadFromFile(str))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Imagem inválida!", L"Erro", MB_OK);
    }

    return texture;
}
```

Depois, vincule a um `sf::Sprite`:

```
sf::Texture textura = LoadTexture(); // chama a função anterior.

// Vincula a texture ao sprite.
sf::Sprite sprite;
sprite.setTexture(textura);
```

E, finalmente, é só desenhar:

```
window.draw(sprite);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Hahaha Meme muito bem colocado! :)

Comment: isso, essa forma eu tinha visto em fórum da própria biblioteca :D, não sei se se você saberia me responder mas eu sei que existe a possibilidade de buscar cada pixel utilizando a mesma biblioteca.

o que estou fazendo é isso, esta correto:
`const sf::Uint8* pixels = imagem.getPixelsPtr();`    

Obs: O meu objetivo é percorrer usando um laço achar os pixels e então substituir por caracteres da tabela ASCII 
Obrigado.Att

Comment: @user3609858 Eu não entendo muito bem. Você quer escrever um texto sobre a imagem? Ou substituir determinados pixels por outro? Se possível, faça um nova pergunta explicando exatamente o que você não está conseguindo fazer, pois resolver isso pelos comentários fica complicado.